# Is using an array as an argument to a macro function just simple text substitution

Tags: c++

A macro function is defined using define in the header file, which uses an array as its parameter

```
#define RFDEVICE_ASM2_TECH_ANT_DATA_2C(temp_sort_array, a, b)\
          (temp_sort_array[0] == a)&&\
          (temp_sort_array[1] == b)
```

The array is defined in the cpp file and this function is used, so is this temp_sort_array a pointer or just a text replacement?

```
 uint8 temp_sort_array[6]
(RFDEVICE_ASM2_TECH_ANT_DATA_2C(temp_sort_array, 5 /*band*/, 4 /*band*/))
```

Comment: macros are text replacement.  Generally they should be avoided in C++.  There are still some use cases, but mainly that is to help write wrappers for verbose code or for conditional compiling.

Comment: All macros are text replacements, that's how they work (and why they are not generally a good idea).

Comment: Preprocrssor macros are just textual/lexical replacement.

Comment: Why is macro substitution not recommended in C++?@NathanOliver @john

Comment: @gordon_zheng Because text substitution is a very crude device which doesn't follow the normal rules of C++. Almost all of the time there is a better alternative. Your macro could be replaced by an inline function for instance.

Comment: @gordon_zheng macros are kind of dangerous.  They exist outside the type system so it is very easy to miss use them and it can be very hard to find that miss use.  C++ offers many other techniques that do the same thing, but are part of the type system and allows the compiler to provide much better diagnostics.

Comment: Is it wise to use inline template functions without macro substitution? How to write if using inline template function?